# Null Pointer Exception When want to set the value in Serializable Class

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to set and get Arraylists from a Serializable class but when we want to set an Arraylist into the Same class it returns NullPointerException, I don't know why? Please suggest me for right result.

**Error Stack:**

```
09-28 11:30:20.422: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 11:30:20.422: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at com.example.test.Test_serializableActivity.parse_json(Test_serializableActivity.java:88)
09-28 11:30:20.422: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(511):     at com.example.test.Test_serializableActivity$2.run(Test_serializableActivity.java:55)
```

**Code: inserting the values Class**

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Test_serializableActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public ArrayList<String> ibx_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> ibx_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> ibx_naturalKey = new ArrayList<String>();
    setIbx ibx;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://qa.mobile.equinix.com/eqixmobile/siteservice/um/ibx");

        try{
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("{\"credentials\":{\"username\":\"mobileuser1\",\"password\":\"welcome1\"}}");
        final Service_Call obj = new Service_Call(post, se, "mobileuser1", "welcome1",false);
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Test_serializableActivity.this, "   EQUINIX                   ", "Loading....   ", true);

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {

           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Test_serializableActivity.this,GetIbx.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                   dialog.dismiss();

              }
           };

           final Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {

               public void run() {
                   ibx_name.clear();
                   ibx_name.add("Select");                                    
                   String json_string = obj.call_Service();
                  // new Parse_Json(json_string).parse();
                   parse_json(json_string);
                   handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
               }
           };
           checkUpdate.start();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void parse_json(String json_string)
    {

        try{
            JSONObject ja = new JSONObject(json_string); 

            JSONArray  jo = ja.getJSONArray("ibx");
            for(int i=0;i<jo.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject j_data = jo.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("The id is:"+j_data.getString("id"));
                ibx_id.add(j_data.getString("id"));
                System.out.println("The Name is:"+j_data.getString("name"));
                ibx_name.add(j_data.getString("name"));
                System.out.println("The naturalKey is:"+j_data.getString("naturalKey"));
                ibx_naturalKey.add(j_data.getString("naturalKey"));

            }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ibx.setId(ibx_id);--------------->**NPE presents**
            ibx.setName(ibx_name);
            ibx.setNaturalKey(ibx_naturalKey);
    }
}
```

**Get the Value Class:**

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class GetIbx extends Activity{

    ArrayAdapter<String> statusAdapter;
    Spinner sp_ibx;
    List<String> ibx_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    setIbx ibx;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newmain);

        ibx_list = ibx.getName();
        sp_ibx = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         statusAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ibx_list);//Sets an status adapter
            statusAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            sp_ibx.setAdapter(statusAdapter);
    }

}
```

Edited: Getter/Setter Class--

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class setIbx implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public List<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> naturalKey = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void setId(ArrayList<String> id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<String> getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setName(ArrayList<String> name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<String> getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setNaturalKey(ArrayList<String> naturalKey)
    {
        this.naturalKey = naturalKey;
    }
    public List<String> getNaturalKey()
    {
        return naturalKey;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you added internet permission in your manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the code you've shown ever sets the `ibx` field in *either* class. That field will always be null, as far as I can see.

Note that this isn't a problem with the `ArrayList` - it's the `setIbx ibx` field which is null. It's not clear to me what the `setIbx` class even *is*, but I would concentrate on working out how you expect this to be non-null rather than the `ArrayList` fields.

Might it be as simple as a statement of

```
ibx = new setIbx();
```

in your constructor? (Or in the field declaration?) I'm not an Android developer, so I may well be off-base, but that's what I think you should be looking at.

Comment: @SanatPandey: But still nothing's ever *creating* an instance of `setIbx` as far as I can see - or setting a value for the field. Do you understand that the default value of that field will be null? (You should also rename your class to follow Java naming conventions and be more descriptive, but that's a separate matter.)

Comment: Ya I know it is my dummy code, but we can not create an abstract class's object.

Comment: @SanatPandey: Why is it abstract in the first place and what are you expecting the value of the ibx field to be? What are you expecting to set it?

Comment: @SanatPandey: That doesn't mean it has to be abstract. You still haven't explained what you expect to set the field - or which concrete type you expect to be used.